# What HTTP Status Code should be used for redirecting to a correct URL?

Tags: http, redirect

I am not so sure if the the title of the question is perfect to ask but here is what I am trying figure out. Of course in relation to SEO and such things.

You might have seen URLs with numbers at the end in addition to the title/slug in the URL. Such as

> /topic/new-topic-at-this-website-1234

The web application actually takes that number (at the end) as an identity to the resource to deliver. So changing that number in the URL brings up another resource but in that case not all but some websites changes the full URL and redirect to the correct resource with correct URL. Even though some websites do not change the URL and just deliver the content.

While I want to redirect the user to correct URL if the numeric values changes, what status code should be used in that case?

Hope I have asked the question correctly.

Comment: You have asked the question correctly, but you didn't do proper research before. Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection For future questions, please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Comment: Thank you Markus, I had gone through wikipedia article before throwing this question out here. From that wikipeida the understanding of the status codes is good indeed but I actually couldn't evaluate what status code should be used in this specific case. Having a hope if I could find a good suggestion about it over here, I asked it. And thanks for the second link, it's useful as I didn't check that before.. I'll sure read it and use the tips for further questions. Thank you :)

Comment: How could one of us decide wether we are talking of a permanent or temporary move. You know your application flow, so you should be able to decide that based on the information you have.

Comment: Of course it's none of the two temporary or permanent. As the resource may be present on the server and would deliver even without redirection. But if not redirected, the URL will not match the canonical on the page. Only the redirection to the correct URL may avoid this case. Or otherwise the changing the URL "/topic/one-two-three-123" to "/topic/one-two-three-987" will be delivering the content of resource id 987 to the wrong URL because content of resource id 987 should be delivered to the URL "/topic/nine-eight-seven-987". I think I was not too clear in my question...

Answer (score 0):

OK, Until I find a suggestion, I am going use status code 301 for such redirection because I just found that in fact stackoverflow is handling the same case with 301. As requesting this page with following link,

> /questions/33775526

redirects to

> /questions/33775526/what-http-status-code-should-be-used-for-redirecting-to-a-correct-url

with status code 301.

[image]

Advices are still welcomed but